# React - native cannot read property 'navigate" of undefined

Tags: react-native, navigation

I'm building an app in react-native and I'm using StackNavigator to navigate.
Here is my problem:

I have my principal page in which I import two other component :

```
export default class RoomChoice extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      create: this.props.navigation.state.params.create,
      join: this.props.navigation.state.params.join
    }
  }

  onCreatePress = () => {
    this.setState({ create: true })
    this.setState({ join: false })
  }

  onJoinPress = () => {
    this.setState({ join: true })
    this.setState({ create: false })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <BtnCreateJoinRoom
          create={this.state.create}
          join={this.state.join}
          onPressCreate={() => {
            this.onCreatePress()
          }}
          onPressJoin={() => {
            this.onJoinPress()
          }}
        />
        {this.state.create ? <CreateRoom /> : <JoinRoom />}
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

Here is my CreateRoom component in which I want to use the navigation to another page :

```
export default class CreateRoom extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
          <BtnComponent title='Créer un code'
                        onPressBtn={() => { this.props.navigation.navigate('CodeCreateRoom') }}/>
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

But When I click it throws error : cannont read property 'navigate' of undefined

```
import {
  createStackNavigator,
  createAppContainer,
  createSwitchNavigator
} from 'react-navigation'

import Home from '../screens/Home'
import RoomChoice from '../screens/Room/RoomChoice'
import CreateRoom from '../screens/Room/CreateRoom'
import CodeCreateRoom from '../screens/Room/CodeCreateRoom'

const AppStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Home: {
      screen: Home,
      navigationOptions: {
        header: null
      }
    },
    RoomChoice: {
      screen: RoomChoice,
      navigationOptions: {
        headerStyle: {
          backgroundColor: BUTTON_SECONDARY_BACKGROUND_COLOR,
          borderBottomWidth: 0
        },
        headerTintColor: 'white'
      }
    },
    CreateRoom: {
      screen: CreateRoom,
      navigationOptions: {
        headerStyle: {
          backgroundColor: BUTTON_SECONDARY_BACKGROUND_COLOR,
          borderBottomWidth: 0
        },
        headerTintColor: 'white'
      }
    },
    CodeCreateRoom: {
      screen: CodeCreateRoom,
      navigationOptions: {
        headerStyle: {
          backgroundColor: BUTTON_SECONDARY_BACKGROUND_COLOR,
          borderBottomWidth: 0
        },
        headerTintColor: 'white'
      }
    }
  },
  {
    headerLayoutPreset: 'center',
    initialRouteName: 'Home'
  }
)
```

I don't understand why it doesn't want to navigate, does anyone have any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only have the navigation prop on direct children of your navigator. Your custom BtnCreateJoinRoom components don't inherit the navigation prop. You must use withNavigation, or pass the prop from one of the direct children.

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/connecting-navigation-prop.html